# Master page and details page for Views

Tags: views, tokens, path-aliases, 7

I have created a new content type and I called it `Opinion`. Then using views, I have created a page with path `/opinion` to be a view for all nodes of type `Opinion` listing i.e. a master page.

The problem is that I could not able to access a the details something like `/opinion/the-node-title`. however, It accesed like `content/the-node-title`

I tried to create a new page from the regarded view with contextal filter `Content title` it works fine using direct access from the browsers address bar. I tried to rewrite the content on the linked title field but I could not able to find a suitable token:

`<a href="[title]">[title]---</a>`

i.e I could not find any way to convert `title` into a slug.

Another thing for SEO, I don't want the same content to be accessed from more than one resource i.e in my case `content/the-node-title` and `opinion/the-node-title`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and configure **URL alias** >> **patterns** >> **content paths** set opinion/[node:title] path alias for opinion content type. All content path for opinion now change as your requirement.

Comment: I have set the path as you said, flush the cache, but still my view get it as `content/node-title`

Comment: New content will be created with alias of opinion/[node:title] apart of that you need to edit content and set its path to opinion/[node:title].

Comment: Pathauto also allows you to reset all aliases - look for a bulk update tab in the URL aliases section.

Comment: Very good, but it seems that I still have a problem with the Views module. I could not able to make the details page from the view. The listing of master page renders everything fine but loading `opinion/the-node-title` seems to load the default display of the content type.